# print hashes with values from different files

Tags: perl, hash, printing

I want to create output file that has values from file 1 and file 2.

The line from file 1:

> chr1    Cufflinks       exon    708356  708487  1000    -       .
>   gene_id "CUFF.3"; transcript_id "CUFF.3.1"; exon_number "5"; FPKM
>   "3.1300591420"; frac "1.000000"; conf_lo "2.502470"; conf_hi
>   "3.757648"; cov "7.589085";      chr1Cufflinks        exon    708356 
>   708487  .       -       .       gene_id "XLOC_001284"; transcript_id
>   "TCONS_00007667"; exon_number "7"; gene_name "LOC100288069"; oId
>   "CUFF.15.2"; nearest_ref "NR_033908"; class_code "j"; tss_id
>   "TSS2981";

The line from file 2:

> CUFF.48557
>   chr4:160253850-160259462:160259621-160260265:160260507-160262715

The second column from this file is unique id (uniq_id).

I want to get output file in the following format:
transcript_id(CUFF_id) uniq_id gene_id(XLOC_ID) FPKM

My script takes XLOC_ID and FPKM values from first file and print them together with two columns from the second file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $v_merge_gtf = shift @ARGV or die $!;
my $unique_gtf = shift @ARGV or die $!;

my %fpkm_hash;
my %xloc_hash;

open (FILE, "$v_merge_gtf") or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /[a-z]/) {
        my @array = split("\t", $line);
        if ($array[2] eq 'exon') {
            my $id = $array[8];
            if ($id =~ /transcript_id \"(CUFF\S+)/) {
                $id = $1;
                $id =~ s/\"//g;
                $id =~ s/;//;
            }

            my $fpkm = $array[8];
            if ($fpkm =~ /FPKM \"(\S+)/) {
                $fpkm = $1;
                $fpkm =~ s/\"//g;
                $fpkm =~ s/;//;
            }

            my $xloc = $array[17];
            if ($xloc =~ /gene_id \"(XLOC\S+)/) {
                $xloc = $1;
                $xloc =~ s/\"//g;
                $xloc =~ s/;//;
            }
            $fpkm_hash{$id} = $fpkm;
            $xloc_hash{$id} = $xloc;
        }
    }
}

close FILE;


open (FILE, "$unique_gtf") or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /[a-z]/) {
        my @array = split("\t", $line);
        my $id = $array[0];
        my $uniq = $array[1];
        print $id . "\t" . $uniq . "\t" . $xloc_hash{$id} . "\t" . $fpkm_hash{$id} . "\n";
    }
}

close FILE;
```

I initialized hashes outside of the files, but I get the following error for each CUFF values:

> CUFF.24093
>   chr17:3533641-3539345:3527526-3533498:3526786-3527341:3524707-3526632
>
> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ex_1.pl
>   line 55,  line 9343.
>
> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ex_1.pl
>   line 55,  line 9343.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I apologize for confusion.
The error is refer to the line with print statement:

print $id . "\t" . $uniq . "\t" . $xloc_hash{$id} . "\t" . $fpkm_hash{$id} . "\n";

Comment: Well, one of the values is uninitialized. Which one is it? Maybe your input data is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the warning message is because the `$id` key, (`CUFF.24093`), you get on line `9343` of the second file isn't contained in the hashes you created in the first file.

Is it possible that an ID in the second file isn't contained in the first file? That seems to be the case here.

If so, and you just want to skip over this unknown ID, you could add a line to your program like:

```
my $id = $array[0];
my $uniq = $array[1];

next unless exists $fpkm_hash{$id}; # add this line

print $id . "\t" . $uniq . "\t" . $xloc_hash{$id} . "\t" . $fpkm_hash{$id} . "\n";
```

This will bypass the following `print` statement and go back to the top of the `while` loop and read in the next line and continue processing.

It depends on what action you want to take if you encounter an unknown ID.

**Update:** I thought I might make some observations/improvements to your code.

```
my $v_merge_gtf = shift @ARGV or die $!;
my $unique_gtf = shift @ARGV or die $!;
```

The error variable `$!` serves no purpose here (this is a fact I only recently discovered even after 14 years using Perl). [$!](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) is only set for system calls, (where you are involving the operating system).The most common are [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and close for files, and [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and closedir for directories. If an error occurs in opening/closing a file or a directory, `$!` will contain the error message. (See in my included code how I handled this - I created a message, `$usage` to be printed if the `shift` didn't succeed.

Instead of using 2 hashes to store the information, I used 1 hash,`%data`. The advantage is that it will use less memory, (because its only storing 1 set of keys instead of 2), Though, you could use the 2 if you like.

I used the recommended 3 argument (`filehandle, mode, filename`) form for opening the files. The 2 argument approach you used is outdated and less safe (for reasons I won't go into detail here). Also, the lexical filehandles I used, `my $mrg` and `my $unique` are the newer ways to create filehandles (instead of using`FILE`for your 2 opens).

You can directly assign to `$line`in your while loop like `while (my $line = <FILE>)` instead of the way you did it. In my sample program, I didn't assign to `$line`, but instead relied on the default variable `$_`. (It simplifies the 2 following statements, `next unless /\S/; my @array = split /\t/;`). I didn't `chomp` for the first file because you're only parsing inside the string and aren't using anything from the end of the string.`chomp` is necessary for the second `while` loop because the second variable `my $uniq = ...` would have a newline at its end if it wasn't removed by `chomp`.

I didn't know what you meant by this statement, `if ($line =~ /[a-z]/)`. I am assuming you wanted to check for empty lines and only process lines with non-space data. That's why I wrote `next unless /\S/;`instead. (says to skip the following statements and got to the top of the while loop and read the next record).

Your first while loop worked because you had no errors in your input file. If there had errors, the way you wrote the code could have been a problem.

The statement`my $id = $array[8];` gives `$id` a value that would have been wrongly used if the following `if` statement had been false. (The same thing for the 2 other variables you want to capture,`$fpkm` and `$xloc`). You can see in my code example how I handled this.

In my code, I died if the match didn't succeed, You might not want to`die` but say `match or next` to try the next line of data. It depends on how you would want to handle a failed match.

And in this line`$array[8] =~ /gene_id "(CUFF\S+)";/`, Note that I put the `";`following the captured data, so there is no need to remove it from the captured data (as you did in your substitutions)

Well, I know this is a long comment on your code, but I hope you get some good ideas about why I recommended the changes given.

`or die "Could not find ID in $v_merge_gtf (line# $.)";`

`$.` is the line number of the file being read.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $usage = "USAGE: perl $0 merge_gtf_file unique_gtf_file\n";

my $v_merge_gtf = shift @ARGV or die $usage;
my $unique_gtf = shift @ARGV or die $usage;

my %data;

open my $mrg, '<', $v_merge_gtf or die $!;

while (<$mrg>) {
    next unless /\S/;
    my @array = split /\t/;
    if ($array[2] eq 'exon') {

        $array[8] =~ /gene_id "(CUFF\S+)";/
            or die "Could not find ID in $v_merge_gtf (line# $.)";
        my $id = $1;

        $array[8] =~ /FPKM "(\S+)";/
            or die "Could not find FPKM in $v_merge_gtf (line# $.)";
        my $fpkm = $1;

        $array[17] =~ /gene_id "(XLOC\S+)";/
            or die "Could not find XLOC in $v_merge_gtf (line# $.)";
        my $xloc = $1;

        $data{$id}{fpkm} = $fpkm;
        $data{$id}{xloc} = $xloc;
    }
}
close $mrg or die $!;


open my $unique, '<', $unique_gtf or die $!;
while (<$unique>) {
    next unless /\S/;
    chomp;
    my ($id, $uniq) = split /\t/;
    print join("\t", $id, $uniq, $data{$id}{fpkm}, $data{$id}{xloc}), "\n";
}

close $unique or die $!;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for valuable suggestion.
I modified line with $id and instead of transcript_id I used gene_id.
From that point $id in a hash and $id from array started to be consistent and I fixed the error.

Comment: @Olha Kholod I've added an update to my post with a lot of information

Comment: Thank you for explaining code line by line. I greatly appreciate your time and work and agree with most of your statements. I am new to programming, so some of my lines can be less complicated as you suggest in your update. I will try to improve my skills to overcome these issues in the future.